# add counter to a variable name delphi

Tags: delphi, for-loop

I have these variables

`edt_variavel := 'Hello'`

`edt_variavel2 := 'Hello2'`

I'm using a `for` loop to find edt_variavels according to the following code :

```
for i := 1 to 10 do
    TEdit(FindComponent('edt_variavel'+IntToStr(i))).Text; //HEllo, //hello2
```

How can i put a counter in a variable name?

i tried something like that...

```
for i := 1 to 10 do
    variavel1+ (i) := TEdit(FindComponent('edt_variavel'+IntToStr(i))).Text;
```

Comment: Don't use 10 different variables. Use an array.

Comment: @GuilhermeLima it is not an idea, it is the only correct solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have stated, you cannot create variable names like you are asking for.  You can use an array instead, eg:

```
var
  variavel: array[1..10] of string;
  i: Integer;

for i := 1 to 10 do
  variavel[i] := TEdit(FindComponent('edt_variavel'+IntToStr(i))).Text;
```

`FindComponent()` has some overhead to it, so you should consider putting your `TEdit` objects in an array as well, such as when the Form is created, then you don't have to hunt for them when needed:

```
private
  edt_variavel: array[1..10] of TEdit;

procedure TMyForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject)
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to 10 do
    edt_variavel[i] := TEdit(FindComponent('edt_variavel'+IntToStr(i))); 

  { or simply:
  edt_variavel[1] := edt_variavel1; 
  ...
  edt_variavel[10] := edt_variavel10; 
  }
end;
```

```
var
  variavel: array[1..10] of string;
  i: Integer;
begin
  ...
  for i := 1 to 10 do
    variavel[i] := edt_variavel[i].Text;
  ...
end;
```

Alternatively, if you really wanted dynamically-named variables, you can use a `TDictionary` instead (though it would have more overhead than an array):

```
var
  variavel: TDictionary<String, String>;
  i: Integer;
  s: string;
begin
  ...
  variavel := TDictionary<String, String>.Create;
  for i := 1 to 10 do
    variavel.Add('edt_variavel'+IntToStr(i), edt_variavel[i].Text);
  ...
  variavel['edt_variavel'+IntToStr(SomeNumber)] := '...';
  ...
  value := variavel['edt_variavel'+IntToStr(SomeNumber)];
  ...
  variavel.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't define a variable name at runtime. You have to use an array.